# What is JavascriptMVC's assertEqual function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, equals, assert, javascriptmvc

I'm a total noob to JavascriptMVC so I'm going through the tutorials. But I have to say something that I'm sure is very simple is totally confusing me. In some of thier tutorials they reference a function `assertEqual()`. Whenever I try to run this in a dev environment my debug tools tell me it can't find the `assertEqual` function. What am I missing? Here's a link to an example of where they use `assertEqual`:

http://javascriptmvc.com/docs.html#!mvc.class

The first reference to it is in the code under the Instantiation sub heading. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are just writing bad examples. It's supposed to illustrate that something is equal to something else.

A naive implementation of `assertEqual` would be

```
function assertEqual(a, b) {
  if (a !== b) {
    throw new Error('values are not equal');
  }
}
```

Comment: Seriously? oh that is stupid, but what you say makes complete sense. I was assuming it was part of their code library and I wasn't referencing the right source or something. It would be nice if they'd explained that, but I guess this is something I should have known. Oh well, I suppose this is how one learns...

Answer (score 0):

I visited the link -- I think its a typo in the documentation.  Try `assertEqual`.